# Rasterize failes in QGIS 3.8

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I'm trying to rasterize a polygon layer which has two columns : id and code.
I would like each polygon to get value according to the code field.

I have used the tool rasterize from the raster menu

[image]

but it keeps failing with the next error message:

> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
> generated.
>
> - C:/Users/hello/this/is/Tmy/processing/fmoreNumbers/OUTPUT.tif
>
> You
> can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
> information about the execution of the algorithm.

why is it failing all the time? what can be the problem? and can I rasterize also based on categorical values?

**Edit: log message:**

Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BURN' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTENT' : '810660.0,844250.0,8123830.0,8145680.0 [EPSG:32721]', 'FIELD' : 'class', 'HEIGHT' : 0, 'INIT' : None, 'INPUT' : 'MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:4326&field=Plot:string(254,0)&field=Crop:string(254,0)&field=Start:string(254,0)&field=End:string(254,0)&field=Grower:string(254,0)&field=Group:string(254,0)&field=Region:string(254,0)&field=Area%2C%20ha:double(23,15)&field=Season%20yea:string(254,0)&field=Code:string(254,0)&field=class:long(10,0)&uid={8ab7aaf2-0e7c-47f2-82d6-dd2abdb6d30c}', 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'UNITS' : 0, 'WIDTH' : 0 }

GDAL command:
gdal_rasterize -l INPUT -a class -ts 0.0 0.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te 810660.0 8123830.0 844250.0 8145680.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff C:/my/path/INPUT.shp C:]my/path/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Wrong value for -outsize parameter.

Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]

{[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add]

[-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]

[-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]*

[-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]*

[-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]

[-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/

CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-optim {[AUTO]/VECTOR/RASTER}] [-q]

<src_datasource> <dst_filename>

Execution completed in 0.33 seconds

Comment: What does the log file show

Comment: @IanTurton sorry, just added it now

Comment: So the issue is "Wrong value for -outsize parameter."

Comment: I don't know why would I  get this error

Comment: Set width and height

Comment: Your width/height = 0.0, that's not going to work.